# before save in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a form with multi-select fields named "city" form in Yii2. When I submit form
the post data show me the following:

```
$_POST['city'] = array('0'=>'City A','1'=>'City B','2'=>'City C')
```

But I want to save the array in serialize form  like:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:6:"City A";i:1;s:6:"City B";i:2;s:6:"City C";}
```

But I don't know how to modify data before save function in Yii2. Followin is my code:

```
if(Yii::$app->request->post()){

    $_POST['Adpackage']['Page'] = serialize($_POST['Adpackage']['Page']);  
    $_POST['Adpackage']['fixer_type'] = serialize($_POST['Adpackage']['fixer_type']);  
}

 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

       return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
  } else {

      return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model   
        ]);
  }
```

Please help me.

Thanks all for your effort. I have solved the issue. here is the code :

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            $this->Page = serialize($_POST['Adpackage']['Page']);
            $this->fixer_type = serialize($_POST['Adpackage']['fixer_type']);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Just put this code in model and its working

Comment: How exactly is that comment useful @AkshayHegde? 
Do you have some sort of `ActiveRecord` / `Model` setup already? If so can you add the code? Where are you trying to save?

Comment: I have used serialize function but data don't save in serialize  form

Comment: Save where? Database? Session? a file? please be more specific in your question, we cannot see your screen nor do we know what you are thinking.

Comment: Sorry for short description. I just want to save data in database. You can check my code sample above and thank for quick reply.

Comment: So far it looks fairly okay (although I would never do serialisation in the controller code). The problem is probably in your model, but you haven't included code of it so it is hard to say. I suspect the `Page` and/or `fixer_type` attributes aren't considered "`safe`" and don't get assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `Yii::$app->request->post()` is different than `$_POST` at this stage. Try to change your code to:

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
$post['Adpackage']['Page'] = serialize($post['Adpackage']['Page']);  
$post['Adpackage']['fixer_type'] = serialize($post['Adpackage']['fixer_type']); 
$model->load($post);
```

**Update:**

Also it would be better to do it on ActiveRecord `beforeSave()` method.

Comment: Also it would be better to do it on ActiveRecord beforeSave() method.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have solved the issue with  beforeSave() method.